# Interactive javascript charting library to display bar graphs on a timeline

Tags: jquery, charts, javascript

I'm looking for a javascript charting library that can display interactive bar graphs on a  timeline, similar to the timeline in Thunderbird's search window.

There are many [javascript libraries to create timelines with line charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890434/javascript-library-for-drawing-graphs-over-timelines-zoomable-and-selectable), but my data requires a bar chart.

Which library should I use  to display my bar graphs interactivly on a timeline?
What is your personal suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used jQuery **[flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)** quite a bit in the past and in combination with **[excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)**, it renders nice interactive charts in all modern browsers.

There are also hooks into the rendering process that allow you to modify how charts are rendered too, if you find that the base script doesn't quite fit with what you require.